# Solr search returns when we search for partial keyword but doesn't return any if we search for actual string

Tags: solr, lucene, solr5

This is the document indexed and stored in solr. I am trying to search by email field and my search term is **alphacomp@gmail.com** then it is not returning any results, but unfortunately, if I search for **alphaco@gmail.com** solr returns this document. That doesn't make any sense.
{
"name"  : "some name",
"email" : "alphacomp@gmail.com"
}
This is the data type of field and filters used

```
            <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
            <analyzer type="index">
                <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15"/>
            </analyzer>
            <analyzer type="query">
                <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
                <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
                <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/>
                <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            </analyzer>
        </fieldType>
```

Can someone please help me debug this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the field type applied to your field?

Comment: Sounds like you're performing stemming or a limited form for ngramming when indexing and not when querying. Add your field definition to your question.

Comment: updated description with datatype and filters used